# Quire API Task.tags are always empty

Tags: quire-api

i use the API to read my projects and tasks with C#. This works like a charm.

I read my tasks with the following endpoints.

https://quire.io/api/task/list/{project.oid}

and

https://quire.io/api/task/list/{task.oid}

However, the tasks have no references to the assigned tags. In the JSON-response the tags-property is always an empty array. But most of my tasks have at least one tag assigned.

Is this a known bug or did i miss something in the documentation?

Thanks for your Help.

Answer (score 0):

I verified the api endpoints you describe. And in my case they result in the expected tags being listed per task. On both root tasks for a {project.oid} and subtasks for another {task.oid}.

Here a screenshot of what I get from command line (formatted the output using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/))

[image]

compared to the view inside quire:

[image]

So the answers to your questions...

No it's not a known bug on our side, and it doesn't look you missed anything based on your description. Maybe the URLs and results from my screenshots give you something to compare with.

If the problem persists on your side you can also contact support@quire.io with additional information you can't share in public.